# Unable to build Cordova Android app in VS2015 - missing shelljs

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 with Windows 10.

I am new to mobile development so I am trying a sample from Github for MS Cordova apps.

I was able to create a Hello World app that pushed to my Samsung Galaxy S5 without issue,

With this sample weather application, the application compiles fine for the Ripple (Galaxy) emulator.  When I attempt to build for my Android device, I get the following error:

BLD401  Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'shelljs'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.

I did clear the Cordova cache (a few times) and nothing seemed to help.

I tried updating the taco.json with 4.3.0 and 6.0.0 but it made no difference. The original value is 5.4.1.  (This as per a similar question posed, and answered by the same person)

Any other suggestions?  Any further information needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of vs Cordova are you using? Can you make sure it is the latest?

Comment: Can you email your build log (the build output) to vscordovatools@microsoft.com